# Find a minimal regular expression for the languge of the words that does not contain bbb

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

Let's say my dictionary is {a,b}
I want to ccind a regular expression for the languge of the words that does not contain bbb in the most minimal way.
All I can think about is '+'ing between prefixes but I think that there is a way to get a shorter answer.

Comment: Minimal according to what measure? Also, it would help if you spelled out the regular expression you have found by your approach.

Comment: Minimal = Shortest. Mine is something like: a*+ (ab)* + (ba)* + (bb)*

Comment: Relevant but without real answer http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12361/minimizing-size-of-regular-expression It seems like the problem is PSPACE complete.

Comment: Your RE can produce abbb, so it contains bbb.

Comment: The shortest I can think of is (a + ab + abb)*

Comment: The above regex doesn't match the string bb. You'd need (b+bb+)(a+ab+abb)*